# Jest - test method that passes to child component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new in testing React component, so I'm trying test some method in parent component that passes to child component as props. I use Jest and Enzyme for this.

My test:

```
it('should be able to call myMethod callback', () => {
  const mockFn = jest.fn();
  ParentComponent.prototype.myMethod = mockFn;

  const wrapper = Enzyme.shallow(<ParentComponent />);
  wrapper.find('ChildComponent').props().myMethod();

  expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

The test passed but myMethod didn't invoke (myMethod doesn't covered by tests).

When I use:

```
wrapper.instance().myMethod = mockFn;
```

instead of:

```
ParentComponent.prototype.myMethod = mockFn;
```

everything is the opposite - myMethod is invoked, but the test is failed with error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question should contain both ParentComponent and ChildComponent because the result depends on how they work. It's not evident that  `ParentComponent.prototype.myMethod === wrapper.instance().myMethod`, and I would expect that it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning `myMethod` to a mock function which doesn't do anything, not even your original `myMethod`. When you are creating `jest.fn()`, what it basically does is creating a dummy mock function which doesn't do anything. So when you call `wrapper.find('ChildComponent').props().myMethod()`, it just call that function but not your `myMethod`.

What you might want to do is to **spy on** your method instead.

```
jest.spyOn(ParentComponent.prototype, 'myMethod'); // ParentComponent.prototype.myMethod is now a mock function

expect(ParentComponent.prototype.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // it works
```